# CD not mounting

Tags: mount

I received a CD from an vendor that has baby pictures on it. When I insert it into the drive, it does not mount. I know my CD-ROM works.
How do I mount the CD within a terminal?
This is what I see when I attempt a mount:

```
*sudo mount /dev/cdrom /mnt/cdrom/
mount: /dev/sr0 is write-protected, mounting read-only
Can only open '/dev/sr0' as read-only
NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/sr0': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sr0' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?*
```

Here is the dmesg:

```
*[ 4726.219094] sr 4:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#14 Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
[ 4726.219096] sr 4:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#14 Add. Sense: Timeout on logical unit
[ 4726.219098] sr 4:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#14 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 2c aa 00 00 02 00
[ 4726.219099] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 45736
[ 4732.776812] sr 4:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#18 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 4732.776815] sr 4:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#18 Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
[ 4732.776817] sr 4:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#18 Add. Sense: Timeout on logical unit
[ 4732.776819] sr 4:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#18 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 2c ab 00 00 01 00
[ 4732.776821] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 45740
[ 4732.776823] Buffer I/O error on dev sr0, logical block 11435, async page read*
```

Comment: It's possible your CD drive doesn't support the type of CD you were given. CD+R vs. CD-R. It's also possible that the CD drive is defective. How do you know it works? Does it work with other discs?

Answer (score 4):

Sorry. I finally found the answer on my own. This is what I used:

```
sudo mount -t iso9660 /dev/cdrom /mnt/cdrom/
```